# Show multiple JPane images on a single JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

First off, I am new to JFrame and all the associated classes so I am still learning how to do this. 
My current goal is to draw multiple images on a single JFrame. So far, I can get test2.png to draw, but not test1.png. Any suggestions or help understanding JFrame is appreciated. This is my main class:

```
package com.osj.oneshotjava;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author BCG04
 */
public class actorTest {
   public static void main(String []args){
      JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("OSJ actor test");
      jFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));                    // sets window size
      jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Actor2 Background = new Actor2(jFrame, "test1.png");
      Actor2 testActor = new Actor2(jFrame, "test2.png");
      jFrame.pack();                                                     // automatically adjusts window size (also sets window size based on the maximum and minimum sizes)
      jFrame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

And this is Actor2:

```
package com.osj.oneshotjava;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author BCG04
 */
public class Actor2 {                     //Purpose: make it easer to add multiple images to a single JFrame using only a single call to Actor2's constuctor rather than repeating the same section of code for each image.
    private BufferedImage image = null;
private JLabel jLabel = null;
   public Actor2(JFrame jFrame, String filename){
      try                                                                      
        {                                                                       // try to load a image 'filename' into 'image'
          image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));                              
        }                                                                       
        catch (Exception e)                                                      
        {                                                                       
          e.printStackTrace();                                                  // if loading fails, print the error
          System.exit(1);                                                       // then exit with an error code 1 'unsuccessful exit'
        }
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);                             // create a new ImageIcon that contains 'image'
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        jLabel = new JLabel();
        jLabel.setIcon(imageIcon);                                              // set JLabel 'jLabel' to contain 'imageIcon'
        jPanel.add(jLabel);
        jFrame.getContentPane().add(jPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);               // makes window visible?

   }

   public JLabel getJLabel(){
      return jLabel;
   }
}
```

Edit:
-removed `Thread.sleep(1000);` and `setLocation(90, 90);` since they were not relevant to the question or the problem and I originally had them in to test whether I could move images.

-removed `jLabel.setBounds` as it did not seem to do anything.

+added a comment clarifying Actor2's goal.

I'd like to clarify my end goal, I would like to create a simple 2d game that uses Java.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1000);` - bad idea, so is `setLocation(90,90)`.  I would suggest having a read of [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).  If would also recommend having a look at [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) as an alternative

Comment: Also, `setBounds` is a bad idea.  Not sure if it's related, but you might want to have a read through [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) if you're trying to do some kind of animation

Comment: `jFrame.getContentPane().add(jPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);` Only one component can be displayed in each position of a `BorderLayout`.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54995980/3992939)  ?

Comment: @c0der No, I am trying to show two images at the same time (overlapping each other).

Comment: I don't usually recommend books, because they go out of date quickly, but this book is a classic that will help you reach your goal.  https://www.amazon.com/Fundamental-2D-Game-Programming-Java/dp/1305076532

Comment: The posted answer should help you with using publicly available images when posting [mre] as well as with swing `Timer`. _ show two images at the same time (overlapping each other)_ so what is the `sleep` for ?  You may want to [edit] the question and clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: One thing you have to consider is that swing has layouts that manage the display. Your game might not be suited to having a swing layout. For example a memory game has all the pieces in a grid, so a gridlayout is good. If you have some Images that are displayed with a free-form, then you might not want to use a layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete, self contained example that is close to what you're after. It is to demonstrate the use of a layout manager.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DuelingJLabels{

    public static void startGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel scene = new JPanel();
        Actor red = new Actor(Color.RED);
        Actor blue = new Actor(Color.BLUE);
        //scene.setLayout( null );
        scene.add(red.image);
        scene.add(blue.image);
        //scene.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(512, 512) );

        frame.add(scene, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    static class Actor{
        int x, y;
        JLabel image;
        public Actor(Color c){
            BufferedImage a = new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics g = a.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(c);
            g.fillOval(0, 0, 64, 64);
            image = new JLabel();
            image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(a));
            image.setLocation( x, y );
            image.setSize( 64, 64);
            image.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter(){
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
                    x = x+64;
                    if(x>=448){
                        x = 0;
                        y += 64;
                    }
                    image.setLocation(x, y);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater( DuelingJLabels::startGui );
    }
}
```

Take note of the line `scene.setLayout(null);` if you run the example with that line commented out, then you will see two circles side by side. That is because we are letting swing handle the layout. `scene` is a JPanel with a `FlowLayout` by default.

Now when you click the circles, *nothing happens** because we tell the new position but the layout manager resets the position. 
**Actually they move sometimes, but if you trigger a re-validation then they get moved by the layout manager.*

So now remove the comment on `scene.setLayout(null);` and notice the difference.

1. The frame is tiny, and we have to manually resize it to see our scene.
2. There is only one circle.
3. If you click on the circle, it moves.

That's because we have told swing to not use a layout manager for the JPanel scene. That means it will not reposition the components in the scene for us, and it will not adjust the sizes for us either.

The other line that is commented `setPreferredSize` makes scene tell the parent component a size it would like to be at. If you uncomment that line then the JFrame will not start out incredibly small. You should only use that with custom components, otherwise you can end up conflicting with the layout manager.

Another tool, which I have found usefull is the [JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) because it gives you some depth. I also think the example is good.

Finally, another technique for putting custom graphics arbitrarily is to @Override paintComponent. That way you can draw whatever, where-ever on your component.